# Lucene error while building index

Tags: java, lucene

I receive an error while building index on file. Here is my piece of code:

```
 try(Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(indexPath.toFile());
    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer()) {

    IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LATEST, analyzer);
    iwc.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
    try (IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(dir, iwc)) {
                     ................

         Field pathField = new StringField(PATH_ATTRIBUTE,
                                           file.toString(), Field.Store.YES)
         Document document = new Document();
         document.add(pathField);
         document.add(new StringField(TYPE_ATTRIBUTE, clazz.getSimpleName(), Field.Store.YES));
         document.add(new TextField(DATA_ATTRIBUTE,
                      new BufferedReader(
                      new InputStreamReader(
                      stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));

         if (indexWriter.getConfig().getOpenMode() == IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND) {
                        indexWriter.addDocument(document);
                    }
    }
```

**Exception** stacktrace:

> 02:36:36.741 [main] ERROR c.r.e.d.service.utils.LuceneUtils -
>   startOffset must be non-negative, and endOffset must be >=
>   startOffset, startOffset=2147483646,endOffset=-2147483645
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: startOffset must be non-negative,
>   and endOffset must be >= startOffset,
>   startOffset=2147483646,endOffset=-2147483645  at
>   org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.PackedTokenAttributeImpl.setOffset(PackedTokenAttributeImpl.java:107)
>   ~[lucene-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:38:43]
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizer.incrementToken(StandardTokenizer.java:208)
>   ~[lucene-analyzers-common-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike -
>   2015-02-27 16:38:59]  at
>   org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardFilter.incrementToken(StandardFilter.java:57)
>   ~[lucene-analyzers-common-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike -
>   2015-02-27 16:38:59]  at
>   org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.LowerCaseFilter.incrementToken(LowerCaseFilter.java:62)
>   ~[lucene-analyzers-common-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike -
>   2015-02-27 16:38:59]  at
>   org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.FilteringTokenFilter.incrementToken(FilteringTokenFilter.java:90)
>   ~[lucene-analyzers-common-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike -
>   2015-02-27 16:38:59]  at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain$PerField.invert(DefaultIndexingChain.java:618)
>   ~[lucene-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:38:43]
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processField(DefaultIndexingChain.java:359)
>   ~[lucene-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:38:43]
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processDocument(DefaultIndexingChain.java:318)
>   ~[lucene-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:38:43]
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:241)
>   ~[lucene-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:38:43]
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:465)
>   ~[lucene-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:38:43]
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1526)
>   ~[lucene-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:38:43]
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addDocument(IndexWriter.java:1252)
>   ~[lucene-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:38:43]
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addDocument(IndexWriter.java:1234)
>   ~[lucene-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:38:43]

I also found this jira https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-5111. Looks like it should be fixed in **4.8** version but it still appear on **4.10.4**.

**UPDATE**

I also checked this on 5.3.0 version and see the same result:

> 15:22:50.649 [main] ERROR developertest.LuceneUtils - startOffset must
>   be non-negative, and endOffset must be >= startOffset,
>   startOffset=2147483645,endOffset=-2147483646
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: startOffset must be non-negative,
>   and endOffset must be >= startOffset,
>   startOffset=2147483645,endOffset=-2147483646  at
>   org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.PackedTokenAttributeImpl.setOffset(PackedTokenAttributeImpl.java:107)
>   ~[lucene-core-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0 1696229 - noble - 2015-08-17 16:59:03]
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizer.incrementToken(StandardTokenizer.java:170)
>   ~[lucene-analyzers-common-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0 1696229 - noble - 2015-08-17
>   16:59:45]     at
>   org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardFilter.incrementToken(StandardFilter.java:36)
>   ~[lucene-analyzers-common-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0 1696229 - noble - 2015-08-17
>   16:59:45]     at
>   org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.LowerCaseFilter.incrementToken(LowerCaseFilter.java:45)
>   ~[lucene-analyzers-common-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0 1696229 - noble - 2015-08-17
>   16:59:45]     at
>   org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.FilteringTokenFilter.incrementToken(FilteringTokenFilter.java:51)
>   ~[lucene-analyzers-common-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0 1696229 - noble - 2015-08-17
>   16:59:45]     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain$PerField.invert(DefaultIndexingChain.java:613)
>   ~[lucene-core-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0 1696229 - noble - 2015-08-17 16:59:03]
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processField(DefaultIndexingChain.java:344)
>   ~[lucene-core-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0 1696229 - noble - 2015-08-17 16:59:03]
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processDocument(DefaultIndexingChain.java:300)
>   ~[lucene-core-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0 1696229 - noble - 2015-08-17 16:59:03]
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:234)
>   ~[lucene-core-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0 1696229 - noble - 2015-08-17 16:59:03]
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:450)
>   ~[lucene-core-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0 1696229 - noble - 2015-08-17 16:59:03]
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1475)
>   ~[lucene-core-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0 1696229 - noble - 2015-08-17 16:59:03]
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addDocument(IndexWriter.java:1254)
>   ~[lucene-core-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0 1696229 - noble - 2015-08-17 16:59:03]